# How to add first array element in to second array

Tags: php

This is first array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [store_lat] => 25.2029
            [store_lng] => 51.4349
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [store_lat] => 25.2029
            [store_lng] => 51.4349
        )

)
```

This is second array

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cust_lat] => 25.2029
            [cust_lng] => 51.4349
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cust_lat] => 25.2029
            [cust_lng] => 51.4349
        )

)
```

I want this format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [cust_lat] => 25.2029
            [cust_lng] => 51.4349
            [store_lat] => 25.2029
            [store_lng] => 51.4349
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [cust_lat] => 25.2029
            [cust_lng] => 51.4349
            [store_lat] => 25.2029
            [store_lng] => 51.4349
        )

)
```

Comment: Always include what you have tried in your question and as a bonus, don't post print_r of arrays use var_export.

Comment: Can you help me it's very urgent

Comment: Yes I can, if you follow what I wrote above and edit your question to include it.

Comment: People here are helping you in their own free time, so please keep “urgent” out of it. How urgent this might be for you, is not relevant to anyone here. If you really _need_ “urgent” support, then you can go and pay for it somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try [this](https://www.php.net/array-merge), here is an example for merging array in PHP

```
<?php
$array1 = array("color" => "red", 2, 4);
$array2 = array("a", "b", "color" => "green", "shape" => "trapezoid", 4);
$result = array_merge($array1, $array2);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: i want like this [1] => Array
    (
        [cust_lat] => 25.2029
        [cust_lng] => 51.4349
        [store_lat] => 25.2029
        [store_lng] => 51.4349
    )

Comment: I think you can do something like:

`$arr1_merged = array_merge($array1[0], $array1[1])`

`$arr2_merged = array_merge($array2[0], $array2[1])`

`$result=array_merge($arr1_merged, $arr2_merged)`

Comment: i would like to looping concept

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the two arrays are always of equal length (or that the second array is always longer than the first one), you can just loop the first and use the key to access the values from the secondary array.

```php
$result = [];
foreach($stores as $key=>$store) {
    $result[] = array_merge($store, $custs[$key]);
}
print_r($result);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/6O4Fe